# BackboneJS - Fetch & Done on Collection - Calling View?

Tags: jquery, json, backbone.js

I am getting the following error for my backbone code:

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

This is happening for line 22 which is:

```
var gallery_item = new window.app.GalleryView({ collection: galleryCollection });
```

Snippet of the code is as follows:

```
    var galleryCollection = new window.app.GalleryCollection();
var gallery_items = galleryCollection.fetch();
gallery_items.done(function(){
    var gallery_item = new window.app.GalleryView({ collection: galleryCollection });
});
```

I'm guessing it something to do with trying to get the GalleryView within the .done function but cannot seem to work out the solution. Can someone see where I am going wrong?

NOTE: If I call:  var gallery_item = new window.app.GalleryView(); seperately ti will work so it's just from within the loop / function causing issues.

Thanks

Comment: Can you throw together the problem in a JSFiddle? This will be solved much quicker if you do.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var galleryCollection = new window.app.GalleryCollection();
var gallery_item;
var gallery_items = galleryCollection.fetch({ 
  success: function(response){
    galleryCollection = response; //or response.items -> it depends on your response 
    gallery_item = new window.app.GalleryView({ collection: galleryCollection });
}});
```

I guess, it will help you